# How do I upload pdf file/blob to S3?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-pdf

I'm using react-pdf library and it generates me a blob and url as shown in the docs: https://react-pdf.org/advanced#on-the-fly-rendering
Blob object copied from the console:

```
{blob: Blob}
blob: Blob
size: 3597607
type: "application/pdf"
[[Prototype]]: Blob
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I try to upload this to S3.
Frontend code:

```
            const fileName = Date.now().toString() + ".pdf";
            const file = new File([blob], fileName);

            axios
              .post("api/upload-poster", {
                fileName,
                file,
              })
              .then(({ data }) => console.log(data));
```

Backend code (nextjs handler):

```
      const { fileName, file } = req.body;

      const params = {
        Bucket: "my-bucket-name",
        Key: fileName,
        Body: file,
        contentType: "application/pdf",
      };

      const uploaded = await S3.upload(params).promise();
      res.status(200).json({ uploaded });
```

I get the error `Error: Unsupported body payload object`

Comment: Q: Can you show us more of the code that's uploading the file?  Is it doing any error checking?  Does it give an error?  SUGGESTION: try this: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-upload-files-to-aws-s3-in-react-591e533d615e

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation for [AWS.S3.Upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property), you need to be passing a buffer, blob object or a stream.

Pass the blob object - *not the blob URL* - back to your API as part of `params` and the rest of your code should work perfectly fine.

Comment: I get `err: Error: Unsupported body payload object`

Comment: Please add how you're generating the blob to the question and I can take a look

Comment: If I go to this url it shows me a pdf file `blob:http://localhost:3000/663bebbc-f5ea-41d5-991e-c44c36af2254`
This is provided by the react-pdf library when pdf is created. They also provide `blob` object. Doc reference: https://react-pdf.org/advanced#on-the-fly-rendering

Comment: If your blob object is an actual blob, the above code works as I've tested it - if you don't add your blob generating code to the question, I'm afraid I can't help anymore

Comment: So blob here should be a string or an object?  var file = new File([blob], filename);

Comment: @Karolis It's an object - check my updated answer, you need to get the raw blob not the URL for it - if you shared how you generated your PDF, I could give you a more succinct answer

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I have updated my post. The react-pdf does it's magic and generates the pdf as shown in that url from docs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237809/discussion-between-ermiya-eskandary-and-karolis).